# Why the text is not rebuilt when resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a function that cuts the text according to how many lines you need and adds a three-dot at the end. If you resize to small devices, everything is ok, if to large - text hidden during resize is not returned. How to fix this error?

[Example](https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/zmqYQO)

```
   function ellipsis() {
            var $this = $('.i-ellips'),
                isOverflow = $this.css('overflow') === 'hidden';

            if (isOverflow) {
                var text = $this.text(),
                    lh = parseInt($this.css('line-height')),
                    line = $this.attr('data-ellipsis'),
                    maxHeight = lh * line;

                for (var i = text.length; i > 0; i--) {
                    if ($this.height() <= maxHeight) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        $this.text(text.substr(0, i) + '...');
                    }
                }
            }
    };

    ellipsis();
    $(window).on('resize', ellipsis);
```

Comment: Because you are literally removing the text from the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store full text before doing any operation on it at the start of your script code file.

```
var full_text=$('.i-ellips').text();
```

then assign its value to your local variable named text on resize event

```
var text=full_text;
```

and assign full_text to text of html element before doing any operations.

```
$this.text(full_text)
```

code: https://codepen.io/peker-ercan/pen/zmqvde

Comment: I'm add var text=full_text; on resize, but it isn't work in my code https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/dgModw

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are grabbing the text and replacing it. The next time you go there, the text is not as the original, is as you left it before. That's why you can remove text but can't add the one removed.

Anyway, you can do what you want only with css.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I return the original text? I know about css way, but I need in js way.

Comment: @jollasf you can store it in a variable when you load the page and never change that variable, only update the element you want with the changes

Comment: Or you can store the original text into a property in your paragraph and always use that property to update the text

Answer (score 0):

I see it is working when you resize down. So, I would say it is because you are working with already shortened text when resizing up, so there isn't the original text available to return.

If it is applicable, solution may be to store original text somewhere like..

```
<div data-original-text="original text that will be used every time for rendering..">trimmed text...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cut the text in the following line

```
$this.text(text.substr(0, i) + '...');
```

but you do not keep the original text, so that you cannot present it when enlarging.

(Also, it would be best to ask these kind of questions with reference to online example e.g., through jsfiddle or similar)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this solution?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  font: 400 14px/1.2em sans-serif; 
  background: white;
}

/* styles for '...' */ 
.block-with-text {
  /* hide text if it more than N lines  */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* for set '...' in absolute position */
  position: relative; 
  /* use this value to count block height */
  line-height: 1.2em;
  /* max-height = line-height (1.2) * lines max number (3) */
  max-height: 3.6em; 
  /* fix problem when last visible word doesn't adjoin right side  */
  text-align: justify;
  
  /* */
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
.block-with-text:before {
  /* points in the end */
  content: '...';
  /* absolute position */
  position: absolute;
  /* set position to right bottom corner of block */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.block-with-text:after {
  /* points in the end */
  content: '';
  /* absolute position */
  position: absolute;
  /* set position to right bottom corner of text */
  right: 0;
  width: 1em;
  /* set width and height */
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<p class="block-with-text">The Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy has a few things to say on the subject of towels. <br>
A towel, it says, is about the most massively useful thing an interstellar hitch hiker can have. Partly it has great practical value - you can wrap it around you for warmth as you bound across the cold moons of  Jaglan Beta; you can lie on it on the brilliant marble-sanded beaches of Santraginus V, inhaling the heady sea vapours; you can sleep under it beneath the stars which shine so redly on the desert world of Kakrafoon;  use it to sail a mini raft down the slow heavy river Moth; wet it for use in hand-to-hand-combat; wrap it round your head to ward off noxious fumes or to avoid the gaze of the Ravenous Bugblatter Beast of Traal (a mindboggingly stupid animal, it assumes that if you can't see it, it can't see you - daft as a bush, but very ravenous); you can wave your towel in emergencies as a distress signal, and of course dry yourself off with it if it still seems to be clean enough. More importantly, a towel has immense psychological value. For some reason, if a strag (strag: non-hitch hiker) discovers that a hitch hiker has his towel with him, he will automatically assume that he is also in possession of a toothbrush, face flannel, soap, tin of biscuits, flask, compass, map, ball of string, gnat spray, wet weather gear, space suit etc., etc. Furthermore, the strag will then happily lend the hitch hiker any of these or a dozen other items that the hitch hiker might accidentally have "lost". What the strag will think is that any man who can hitch the length and breadth of the galaxy, rough it, slum it, struggle against terrible odds, win through, and still knows where his towel is is clearly a man to be reckoned with.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. But I need it in js.